# How to "refresh" a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have this issue with my current program; I simply can't figure out how to "refresh" the JFrame so it correctly displays the changes to the variable vangle. I have of course imported all the correct files. Is there any advantage to using a JPanel instead of a JFrame? Please give it your best shot! :)

```
public class projekt {
    static int vangle = 20;
        public static void main(String args[]) {new FractalTree().setVisible(true);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton b1 = new JButton();
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        b1.setSize(20, 20);
        b1.setVisible(true);
        b1.setText("vinklen + 10");
        frame.add(b1);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //stoppe når jframen bliver lukket lukker begge jframes
            b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    vangle = vangle + 10;
                    System.out.println("angle:" + vangle);


                }
            });
    }



    public static class FractalTree extends JFrame {
        public FractalTree() {
            super("Fractal Tree");
            setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
            setResizable(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); /* stopper når den lukker, lukker begge Jframes */
        }

        public static void drawTree(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, double angle, int depth) {
            if (depth == 0) return;
            int x2 = x1 + (int) (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 10.0); /* skifter størelsen på den */
            int y2 = y1 + (int) (Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * depth * 10.0);
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            drawTree(g, x2, y2, angle - vangle, depth - 1); /* skifter vinklen */
            drawTree(g, x2, y2, angle + vangle, depth - 1);


        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.blue); /* skifter farven */
            drawTree(g, 400, 500, -90, 9);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to keep a variable reference to the created `FractalTree instance = new FractalTree()` and call instance.repaint() for the

Comment: this might be a stupid question but where do i put the code?

Comment: @Sophie See my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to call `repaint();` on the FractalTree.  In order to do that, you need a reference to it, e.g.

```
    final FractalTree tree = new FractalTree();
    tree.setVisible(true);
```

and then your method becomes:-

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            vangle = vangle + 10;
            System.out.println("angle:" + vangle);
            tree.repaint();
        }
```

And one final point, you need to clear the previous drawing of the tree first, otherwise your new tree will draw over the top of the old one.

EDIT: There are obviously a lot of problems with OP's code and it could do with a complete rewrite; however my understanding (as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266572/answer-question-or-improve-code ) is that the primary aim of SO is to answer a user's specific question, which my answer aims to do.

Comment: While this might address the immediate question the whole code needs to be rewritten and redesigned. You should not be doing custom painting at the frame level. You should not be using static variables and methods for the painting.

Comment: `How exactly do I clear pervious drawing ?` - the custom painting tutorial shows how this is done. So you could spend time reading the tutorial to find a working example or you can sit here for 30 minutes (and counting) hoping that you get a response. Put your time to good use and learn the proper way to code the class.

Comment: @sophie engelbreth, just draw a blank rectangle before drawing the tree.  And feel free to upvote if you found this answer useful in any way. :)

Comment: I've tried to follow the link you sent @camickr, but I simply can't get it to work, I'm the dumbest of the dumb.

Steve Smith, when I try to draw the blank rectangle, nothing appears to happen in the JFrame at all, and it keeps adding more and more lines to my fractal trees (as it should when one can't add a blank rectangle over it). Any pointers? (I did try upvoting, but my account is brandnew, so I can't :-/ )

Comment: I'm curious why this answer is getting downvoted when it clearly answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. The structure of your whole code is wrong. Anytime you use static variables and methods you know you have a design problem.
2. You should NOT be overriding paint() on a JFrame. Instead you should be overriding `paintComponent()` on a JPanel and add the panel to the frame.
3. Anytime you change the value of a property used in the painting of the class you need to invoke `repaint()`.

I suggest you start over and read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html) for more information and working examples.

Start with the working example and modify the code for your requirement. The example will show you how to define variables that control the painting properties in the class that actually does the painting.

Comment: Thank you for the incredible response, I agree that I need to start with the basics, but I have a deadline coming where this just needs to work in the moment and not be structurally correct ^_^